# How to send audio files using net/http in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I want to send audio file via http request as an api cal, not via form using net/http. I dont want to use any other gems. Please let me know how it can be achieved. Below is my ruby script.

```
require 'net/http'  
require "uri"

data = File.read('/root/Desktop/amc.amr')

url = URI.parse('http://localhost:3000/api/applications')

http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)

response, body = http.post(url.path, data, {'Content-type'=>'audio/amr;
charset=utf-8'})

puts response
```

Comment: can't you send url of your audio file ?

Comment: I have  my audio file in my local machine say "user/a1.amr"

Comment: Why not use `curl` or the [curb](http://rubygems.org/gems/curb) gem?

Comment: @tadman and naveed thanks for you replies, I got it working using net/http itself :)

Answer (score 3):

Got it by the below code:

```
require 'net/http'
require "uri"

url = "http://#{domain}:#{port}"
uri = URI.parse(url);

data = File.read('fil_path')  #File.read("/usr/test.amr") 

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
request.body = data
request.content_type = 'audio/amr'

res = http.request(request)
puts res.body
```